# how to disable or enable all onClick for images on a page

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, image

When the user clicks on an image, I want the onClicks on all other images to be disabled until my function has finished.

I currently have this code that disables them:

```
var eles = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i < eles.length; i++)
   eles[i].onclick = false;
```

but I'm not sure how to re enable them. I have tried:

```
var eles = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i < eles.length; i++)
   eles[i].onclick = true;
```

But its not working. anyone have solution for this problem

Comment: This problem you have reveals the fact that you bind click handlers incorrectly. If you are in control and can change it, please remove all `onclick` attributes and in JS use the the `addEventListener` method or use a framework like jQuery for wider browser support. Then you can bibnd the events when you're ready

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution doesn't work because you removed your onClick with onClick = false. After that you need to create the onClick event handler again.

This is probably your way of adding onclick events, I changed it so it should work.

```
<img src="image1.jpg" onclick="when_i_click();"/>
<img src="image2.jpg" onclick="when_i_click();"/>
```

*Try adding a function to your onclick as above.*

**Your onclick function:**

```
var when_i_click = function(){
    alert('image clicked!');
}
```

**This is how you disable your onclicks (your method)**

```
var eles = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i < eles.length; i++)
   eles[i].onclick = null;
```

**This is how you re-enable them (re-attach function to onClick )**

```
var eles = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i < eles.length; i++)
   eles[i].onclick = when_i_click;
```

**This is a Jquery solution jquery:**

Try using unobstructive javascript, by not adding onclick event handlers in the DOM.

```
<script>
(function(){
    var function_is_finished = false;
    $('img').on('click',function(event){
        if(function_is_finished) {
            //Do your stuff when someone clicks on Img
        }
    });
})();
</script>
```

When your function is finished just set `function_is_finished` to `true`

Comment: what if i want some parameters to be sent to that function, is there a way to do that...?

Comment: does resetting the onclick value: "eles[i].onclick = when_i_click; " actually call the function the moment you reset it?

Comment: No it does not.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to save the previous value of onclick and restore it:

```
var disable_all = function () {
    var eles = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i=0; i < eles.length; i++) {
      eles[i].prev_click = eles[i].onclick; // save the previous value
      eles[i].onclick = false;
    }
}

var enable_all = function() {
    var eles = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i=0; i < eles.length; i++)
       eles[i].onclick = eles[i].prev_click;  // restore the previous value
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

onclick it suppposed to be pointing to a javascript function.
instead of onclick try with.

```
eles[i].disabled="true"
```

and at the end of your method back to eles[i].disabled="false"

Answer (score 0):

by setting `eles[i].onclick = false;` you are reassigning the `onclick` event to `false`. setting back to true does not assign it back to the original function.  It is probably better to handle the un-assigning in the event function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're setting the elements' `onclick` to `false` and `true`.
it's the equivalent of doing something like

```
<img src=".." onclick="false"/>
```

then

```
<img src=".." onclick="true"/>
```

What you should do is maintaining some variable that you check against to see if you can start the function or not.

```
locked = false;
function yourFunction() {
    if (locked) {
        locked = true;
        //... Do what you have to do here
        locked = false;
    };
}
```