# Turning on and off an element's onclick properties

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to delay the load of a pop-up on a grid of images but want to prevent the ability to click on other images when this happens.  Howver if I turn off onclick 'item.onclick = false', I don't seem to be able to turn it back on when the pop-up is turned back on? see line 'item.onclick = true'.  Have also tried disabled = true/false but to no avail.  Any suggestions?

```
var caseStudies = document.querySelectorAll('.posterImage');
var caseHover = document.querySelectorAll('.caseHover');
var modal = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

caseStudies.forEach((button, index) => {

    if ((isMobile == true) || (isTablet == true)) {
        button.onclick = function(event) {
            caseStudies.forEach((item) => {
                item.onclick = false;
                console.log(item);
            });
            caseHover.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.add('eventsNone');
            console.log(item);
            });
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("loading");
            modal[index].style.display = "block";
    
      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it (needs to live inside the button.onclick)
            
            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (event.target == modal[index]) {
                modal.forEach((item) => {
                item.style.display = "none";
            });
            caseStudies.forEach((item) => { 
    item.onclick = true;
            }); 
                        }
                    }
            },  500); 
        }
    }   
    else
    {
button.onclick = function(event) {
            console.log("route2");
            modal[index].style.display = "block";
            caseStudies.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.add('eventsNone')
            });

      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it (needs to live inside the button.onclick)

            window.onclick = function(event) {

                if (event.target == modal[index]) {
                modal.forEach((item) => {
                item.style.display = "none";
            });
                caseStudies.forEach((item) => {
                item.classList.remove('eventsNone')
            });
                    };
                };
            };  
    };
});
```

Comment: Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) instead.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use an inline `onclick = "function()"` to set your onclick.

When disabling your onlick do it with `element.onclick = null`.

And enable it again with `element.onclick = "function()"`

Sorry for getting it wrong before I miss read it and thought you were doing it with buttons.

Also here is a duplicate question [how to disable or enable all onClick for images on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003526/how-to-disable-or-enable-all-onclick-for-images-on-a-page)

Comment: The elements being clicked in OPs question are images, not buttons. Setting disabled = true is a pointless exercise - the click handler is still called.

Comment: Oh I see. Add a `onclick = "function()"` to your images and define `function`. Then to disable onclick set `onclick` to `null` and to enable them set `onclick` to `"function()"` again.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I struggled to make it work in the context of the code (I think because the function is located inside a function but by turning the functions into variables I managed to make it work.  Thanks!